# YouTube API for a channel from a specific user

Tags: youtube-api

I was looking at channels in YouTube and saw this link below and other stackoverflow messages.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search.html

My question is, is it possible to return a YouTube channel from a specific user?  For instance, say I wanted the channel of..

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/NationalGeographic
```

What would this query look like?  I can get to the query of say "search for videos about national geographic with...

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?q=nationalgeographic&v=2&alt=json

But how do I say return all the videos for this specific channel (rather than searching the channels).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could search by author.

See:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html#authorsp

Example API uri:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=NationalGeographic&v=2&alt=json
```

Comment: @david99world, what did you mean, to use Partner?